# Should upsertQueryData be used to simulate the response of an initial query in which the API does not return data

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I have an API which allows for saving/fetching user preferences. For new users, that have not saved an preferences, the API will respond with `undefined`.

I'm trying to determine how to handle this case in "RTK Query way". Should I check for `undefined` in a `useEffect`, and then dispatch `upsertQueryData` with the initial state, alongside a save request as well? Then the following query would not trigger a network request, because the data would be in the cache already?

Or is there a better way to handle an initial request that has no data?

Initially, I was using `extraReducers` to set an "initial state", however I realized that there would be 2 sources of truth, the initial state, and the saved state in the BE (which would be `undefined`), and I'm not sure how to reconcile them.